# Migrating a TortoiseSVN repository to another folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a TortoiseSVN repository on my C: drive. I've recently installed a new hard drive and would like to migrate the repository to the D: drive.  How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- You have a **Subversion** repository. TortoiseSVN is in the name of the client only.

You have (at least) two ways of migration:

- Because physically the repository is just a subtree on the file system, you can move the corresponding directory to a new location.
- Pure Subversion way: You can `svnadmin dump` an old repository, `svnadmin create` the repository in a new location, and `svnadmin load --force-uuid` dump into a new repository.

In any case: If the repository is served by Apache/svnserve you have to check and change some configurations, if needed.

In case of using the `file:///` access method, you must only relocate all working copies of this repository.